Find Maximum in Assembly code does not work for 64 bits register
I am following a book about Assembly for x86 called "Programming Ground UP" from Jonathan Bartlett.
The examples are written to x86 architecture and I am trying to adapt to x64.
Many examples fails to compile if written as x86 mainly because commands like
push %eax are not allowed. However the original code to find a maximum in a list works since it has not push or pop commands. The original example is as below
.section .data
data_items:
#These are the data items
    .long 3,67,34,222,45,233,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0
    .section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $0, %edi
# move 0 into the index register
movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax # load the first byte of data
movl %eax, %ebx
# since this is the first item, %eax is
# the biggest
start_loop:
# start loop
cmpl $0, %eax
# check to see if we’ve hit the end
je loop_exit
incl %edi
# load next value
movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
cmpl %ebx, %eax
# compare values
jle start_loop
# jump to loop beginning if the new
# one isn’t bigger
movl %eax, %ebx
# move the value as the largest
    jmp start_loop

    loop_exit:
# %ebx is the return value, and it already has the number
movl $1, %eax
#1 is the exit() syscall
int $0x80


It works. Then I tried to adapt this code using x64 register as
    #Get the maximum from a list

    .section .data
data_items:
    .long 1,2,23,5,7,0

    .section .text
    .globl _start
_start:
    mov $0, %rdi
    mov data_items(,%rdi,4), %rax
    mov %rax, %rbx

start_loop:
    cmp $0, %rax
    je loop_exit
    inc %rdi
    mov data_items(,%rdi,4), %rax
    cmp %rbx, %rax
    jle start_loop
    mov %rax, %rbx
    jmp start_loop
loop_exit:
    #mov %rdi,%rbx
    mov $1, %rax
    int $0x80

but it does not work
I tried to change the mov command as mov data_items(,%rdi,8), %rax as I thought that the .long type could have 8 bytes long, but it did not work. I also tried to put %rdi as the return value to test if the total number of reading from the list was correct and actually it is, I mean, in this case the return value correspond to the size of the list.
I really do not know what can be wrong

Confusingly .long is still 32 bits. You want .quad if you want to extend the data type. Otherwise you can keep using 32 bit registers (except for addresses).

Your adaptation for 64 bit registers assumes the data is also 64 bit, but it is not.  Either keep the data 32 bit and load it using appropriate (signed or unsigned) extension to 64 bit, or convert the data to 64 bit and use scale factor of 8.

Thanks @Jester. I changed the code using .quad 1,2,202,23,5,74,55,99,121,189,0 in the list and in the code I got each value with "mov data_items(,%rdi,8), %rax". It works. However if I use .long for the list and "mov data_items(,%rdi,4), %rax" to get the values the program does not work

For 32-bit (dword) lists you want mov data_items(,%rdi,4), %eax" (for example, this uses zero-extension)

@ErikEidt how can I load 32 bit data. Is it not something like "mov data_items(,%rdi,4), %rax" ? The problem here is that I am putting a 32 bit integer in a 64 bits register?

Thanks @ecm. It worked. Problem solved

You can look at C compiler generated code to see how to do things, e.g. int foo(int *arr, int idx) { return arr[idx]; }, and play around with stuff like changing the return type to long, or casting to (unsigned) to force zero-extension instead of sign-extension to a 64-bit return type.  Use GCC -O1 or -O2 on https://godbolt.org/.  How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?
